# PHP HTTP_REFERER issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, http-referer

I have a problem with http_referer.

I have 1 file, index.php that has form and when the form is submitted, information like the http_referer is submitted.

There's another file, index.html that runs an ajax script that submits the same info as index.php file would but with just a click of a button.

When I run the action from index.php the http_referer is localhost/index.php
When I run the ajax script from index.html the http_referer is localhost/index.html

how can I make the http_referer be localhost/index.php from the index.html?

Someone suggested I framed index.php in index.html but when I did that and ran the ajax script the http_referer was still localhost/index.html

Edit: Ajax file added

```
function ajax_func(){

var ajax;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

  ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

} else {

  ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){

  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){



  }
}

ajax.open('POST', 'index.php', true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajax.send('name=johndoe&email=jd@email.com&tasks=value');

 alert('script ran');
```

}

Comment: Relevant code for your `AJAX` please

Comment: You can't change the refer value, it's handled by the browser and because of that -- it might even be different or empty for different browsers. Maybe you can tell us why you need the refer to be a

Comment: I added the ajax file @Aditya

Comment: @DaveChen I want to know if it's possible for security reasons

Comment: Please do **not** use this value for security reasons. As stated before, this value can not be relied because it is sent by the browser. Please explain how you plan to use this for security reasons.

Comment: @mattchambers, the XHR object does not allow you to set the refer, you will get a `Refused to set unsafe header "Referer"` error if you try. Also note that since you can set it using other languages like with cURL in php etc http_referer cannot be relied on as it can be faked

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thank you for telling me that

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_REFERER is the page where you were before you went to the next page. If you run anything from index.html that leads elsewhere, the http_referer is index.html. Likewise with index.php. So, you cannot make index.php the http_referer when executing from index.html.

As an example, I use it in php to return to the initial page. This way, I can use a single script for multiple pages. (obvious and simple, I know)